# Filtering and Extracting from XML

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an `XML` File like this:

```
<article>
   <section> 
      <H4>Table of Contents </H4>
      <p> Content_ID_1 </p>
      <p> content_ID_2 </p>
      <p> content_ID_3 </p>
   </section>
   <section>
      <p>Content_ID_1 </p>
      <p>content_ID_2 </p>
   </section>
</article>
```

I am trying to extract the `Content_ID` 1 and 2 from the second section using `Xpath`. Obviously, `Section1` is the first hit and the results are being returned from the table of contents.

The command I gave is:

```
"//article//section//p[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'content_id_2') ]/text()";
```

Obviously,this returns the first `content_ID_2` from the table of contents section. Is there any way using `XPath` I can filter out the first section and have it only return the value from the second?

Thanks in advance.
-simak

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
"//article//section[not(H4)]//p[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'content_id_2') ]/text()";
```

The **[not(H4)]** selects only those `section` nodes which don't have a `H4` node as their direct child, which is the case here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your response. But sorry, this did not work - it actually returned NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always going to be 2nd then yes, `//article//section[2]` filters down to 2nd section and the remaining path should work as usual.

Comment: unfortunately, it may or may not be the second section always.

Comment: what tells for which section to filter